# Pinterest Style Masonry Grid with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, pinterest, angular-masonry

This Masonry grid has to take into account both differing height and widths. Any hint on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap has an implementation of this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns) called `card-columns`. It works very well for your requirements.

Comment: card-columns does not take into account different card heights and widths at the same time, only one or the other.